# MAMP Pro 2.0.2 - Mysql db's synced on dropbox have somehow become out of sync?

Tags: mysql, synchronization, mamp, dropbox

I am using Dropbox to synchronize some MAMP mysql databases via a symlink as per [this tutorial](http://wesbos.com/dropbox-your-mamp-mysql-databases/). They are synced between my  laptop and desktop.

For quite some time, everything has worked perfectly. I haven't changed anything and all of a sudden I've noticed the db's are out of sync. For example, in a wordpress database, I have made several changes that aren't reflected on the other computer, even after Dropbox has plenty of time to 'sync' up, and Mamp is running on only one system and quit before opening on the other.

Running

> Tools > Check MySQL Databases

Shows every relevant db/table to be 'OK'

Both computers are symlinked to the same folder, so I'm really not sure what is going on here. I'm really unsure how to trouble shoot this as even the dropbox revision/file history shows no conflicts or anything. It's as though the data is being stored somewhere else even though both are linked to the same place.

To remedy, I've had to make a mysqldump from one system and reimport it to the other, but this defeats the purpose.

If anyone has a tip for how to begin troubleshooting this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental difference between what you're doing and what the article recommended. The article was using dropbox as a one-way sync. So only running MySQL server on one server, then using Dropbox to store a remote copy of the database in "The Cloud."

In your case, it sounds like you're trying to synchronize two running MySQL Servers using Dropbox. MySQL isn't designed to work this way. There's a whole (complex) feature for this purpose called [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html). I'd strongly discourage you from using Dropbox to sync a database which has MySQL servers running on more than one machine.

Regarding the failure to sync, it sounds like a Dropbox issue. Do you have sufficient space left? You may need to contact their support to see why your symlinks aren't syncing properly.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why it is a problem to do this? As I mentioned in my post, I always make sure to stop one MAMP server before starting the other, so technically only one is running at a time. Regarding Dropbox, it's definitely confusing me as I am only using 35% of 65 gigs and it states "All files up to date"

Comment: OK. Problem solved, and silly on my part. MAMP have still had a lock on the files on one of the DBs before I opened the other, and thus it created a whole new folder where it had been storing db's.

Strange, but that definitely explains the syncing problem. Perhaps this is the reason you were mentioning above, I will try to look into replication.

Comment: You also could store a one cloud copy of the db folder in dropbox and create a link from dropbox copy to mamp folder. So mamp only works only the files in dropbox.